# Javascript Images in Append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an image link into this javascript append to table. So that the image is above the button

Here is the code

```
 $("#1").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
  $("#1").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
   });
```

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks
Sam

EDIT

Here is the code

```
   for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {



             var section = json.results[i].section;



             var no = json.results[i].avalible;



             var price = json.results[i].price;



             var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='glaisdale.co.uk'>Compare</button>";




  $('#1 .redirect-button').before('<img src="extreamlylongurlpathhere" alt=""></a>');
     $("#1").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");

   $("#1").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){

   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");

    });

           }

     },

     error: function(error){

                console.log(error);

     }

  });
```

Again this is whoile code. It is a big off a mess i know sorry :)

Comment: How your code fails? Where is the button? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried putting in `<img src="/path/here">` before the `+button+` but i just get a red error in dreamweaver

Comment: Then you should show us the real code you have, and explain what you want it to do, and what it does instead, _in your question_ , please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>If you want to put the link-image just before the button, you should try with jQuery `.before()`. Something like that should work:</del>

```
$('#1 .redirect-button').before('<a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>');
```

In the comment you explained how the table became weird, the reason seems to come from a bad html syntax (the opening tag of your link is missing):

```
$('#1 .redirect-button').before('<img src="extreamlylongurlpathhere" alt=""></a>');
```

But, thanks to your edit, I can see now that the `before()` solution is not the best for this case.
It would be better to remove it and add the image exactly like you added the `button`.

```
var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='glaisdale.co.uk'>Compare</button>";
var linkImg = "<a href='#'><img src='extreamlylongurlpathhere' alt=''></a>";
$("#1").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+linkImg+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
```

You can find a code snippet here:

```js
/*fake JSON*/
var json = {};
json.results = [];
json.results = [{
    section: 'a',
    avalible: '1',
    price: '12'
},{
    section: 'b',
    avalible: '2',
    price: '12'
},{
    section: 'c',
    avalible: '3',
    price: '12'
}];

/*loop*/
for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {
    var section = json.results[i].section;
    var no = json.results[i].avalible;
    var price = json.results[i].price;
    var button = "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='glaisdale.co.uk'>Compare</button>";
    var linkImg = "<a href='#'><img src='extreamlylongurlpathhere' alt=''></a>";

    //$('#1 .redirect-button').before('<a href="#"><img src="extreamlylongurlpathhere" alt=""></a>');
    
    $("#1").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+section+"</td><td>"+no+"</td><td>"+price+"</td><td>"+linkImg+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
    $("#1").find(".redirect-button").click(function(){
        location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
    });
}
```

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}
table td, table tr{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="1">
</table>
```

Comment: Hi there, So the table is being weird now. The images are being put in with the amount of rows? So for example. the top row has 3 images ontop of the button. The 2nd row and 2 images, 3rd row has 1 image. and the last row has no images.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to understand your question. Can you show us your code?  Here, the explanation of what my example does: "For each occurence of `.redirection-button` add a link-image just before it."